# read input file, match and remove data and write remaining lines to a new file

Tags: perl

I am stuck trying to get this to write out the contents of the file. What I am trying to do is open an input file, filter out/remove the matched line and write to a new file. Can someone show me how to do this properly? Thanks.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1 }) or
     die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV_XS->error_diag ();
open my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-16LE)", "InputFile.txt" or die "cannot open file: $!";

my @rows;
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    my @lines;
    shift @lines if $row->[0] =~ m/Global/;

    my $newfile = "NewFile.txt";

    open(my $newfh, '>', $newfile) or die "Can't open";
    print $newfh @lines;

    }
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag ();
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the output file outside of the loop. As you read each line, decide if you want to keep it. If yes, write to output file. If not, don't do anything.

Something like the following (untested):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my ($input_file, $output_file) = qw(InputFile.txt NewFile.txt);

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1 })
    or die sprintf("Cannot use CSV: %s\n", Text::CSV_XS->error_diag);

open my $infh, "<:encoding(UTF-16LE)", $input_file
    or die "Cannot open '$input_file': $!";

open my $outfh, '>', $output_file
    or die "Cannot open '$output_file': $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($infh)) {
    next if $row->[0] =~ m/Global/;
    unless ( $csv->print($outfh, $row) ) {
        die sprintf("Error writing to '%s': %s",
            $output_file,
            $csv->error_diag
        );
    }
}

close $outfh
    or die "Cannot close '$output_file': $!";

close $infh
    or die "Cannot close '$input_file': $!";

$csv->eof
    or die "Processing of '$input_file' terminated prematurely";
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It works well. Is it possible to control the print formatting on `$csv->print($outfh, $row)` when creating the new file? thanks again

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by controlling print formatting. Can you give an example?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. the format is actually fine. what happened is when writing out to the new file, the new file is more ascii text without all the utf8 encoding. this is actaully a better input file to work with. thanks.

Comment: If you need a specific encoding, you should be able to specify that when you open the output file.